# Spring Boot w/ JSP - Not finding CSS files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

*This is a spring boot app using jsp*
I've tried many solutions, but I can't seem to get CSS integrated with my JSP files. My JSP files are under /WEB-INF/jsp and my css files are in /resources/static/css.

^ The first one doesn't work, but the second one with the link works.

Application.properties file:

```
#
# MVC Properties
#
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/tfhk
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

Project structure: 
[link to project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6zJn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view:

```
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also somewhere in your config do this (in spring security context if using it):

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
};

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

Comment: What I did was I clicked on the CSS file and copied the qualified name. This seemed to help identify the path of the file. However, I'm facing another issue:
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/tfhk/src/main/resources/static/css/sb-admin.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: For this issue remove leading slash for your css path like this - css/sb-admin.css instead of /css/sb-admin.css